# How do I redirect a dynamic subdomain also based on query string?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my site which redirects all *.domain.com calls to domain.com.
What I want to acheive is that first when the user enters a dynamic subdomain name he should be directed to its home page like 
if user writes  `division1.domain.com`, then the site should point to page `division.php?value=division1`, and when the user accesses `division1.domain.com/news/newsdetails.php` then this should call the page `news.php` with argument `value=division1`. Similarly if I call the news page form the base url like `domain.com/news/newsdetails.php` then this should not include any arguments.

Here is the current htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com/(news/newsdetails.\.php)$  [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^www$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)(.*)$ news.php?div=%1$1&filter=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

# For www.domain.com it should go to the index page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]

# For Accessing Divisions Page

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ divisions.php?username=%1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:

```
# redirect ******XX.domain.com 
# to       domain.com/*******.php?value=******XX
# where XX is a number...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !news/newsdetails\.php$           # not news page
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}!^www\.domain\.com                   # prevent rewrite www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(([^.]+)[0-9]+)\.domain\.com$      # catch subdomain
  RewriteRule .* http://domain\.com/%2.php?value=%1 [R=301, L] # Redirect

# redirect ******.domain.com/news/newsdetails.php
# to       domain.com/news.php?value=******
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} news/newsdetails\.php$ # news page
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}!^www\.domain\.com        # prevent rewrite www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$   # catch subdomain
  RewriteRule .* http://domain\.com/news.php?value=%1 [R=301, L] # Redirect

# redirect domain.com/news/newsdetails.php
# to domain.com/news.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} news/newsdetails\.php$ # news page
  RewriteRule .* /news.php?value=%1 [L]             # Redirect
```

to your htaccess file.